# Function to change checkboxes not working on dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table that each row has three checkboxes, what I am trying to do is have it so only one checkbox can be selected per row. If a checkbox is checked, the other checkboxes will be unchecked. The code that I currently have is the following:

```
$('#idCheckboxOne').on 'change', ->
  if $('#idCheckboxOne').prop('checked')
    $('#idCheckboxTwo').prop 'checked', false
    $('#idCheckboxThree').prop 'checked', false

$('#idCheckboxTwo').on 'change', ->
  if $('#idCheckboxTwo').prop('checked')
    $('#idCheckboxOne').prop 'checked', false
    $('#idCheckboxThree').prop 'checked', false

$('#idCheckboxThree').on 'change', ->
  if $('#idCheckboxThree').prop('checked')
    $('#idCheckboxTwo').prop 'checked', false
    $('#idCheckboxOne').prop 'checked', false
```

So this code will work on the first row of my table, but not any other row. I know that part of my problem is that Im using the function by the checkbox's ids, so since each table row has the same checkboxes, the ids are not unique for the other table rows. So my question is what is the best approad for having the above functionality for each table row?

Comment: "what I am trying to do is have it so only one checkbox can be selected per row. If a checkbox is checked, the other checkboxes will be unchecked." Usually, this is done with radio buttons.

Comment: Can you show the issue in a fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Only one of the radio buttons having same name can be selected.
2. If for some reason you want to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons, you can use class instead of ids:

   ```
   $('.classCheckboxOne').on 'change', ->
     if $('.classCheckboxOne').prop('checked')
       $('.classCheckboxTwo').prop('checked', false)
       $('.classCheckboxThree').prop('checked', false)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a generic solution for *any* checkbox that you put the `.group-checks` class on. This will also be parent agnostic, so it could be in a row, div - it doesn't matter as long as the checkboxes are in the same container.

```
// attach handler to all checkboxes    
$('input:checkbox.grouped-checks').change(function(event) {
  // get the container of the checkbox clicked
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  // unchecked all inputs in the container
  $parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  // check the one you clicked on
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Here's the codepen: